# Object tracking not matching

Tags: rendering, animation, tracking

I'm trying to track an object from footage in Blender.

I've exported it from AE and put it in the camera same fps and resolution.

When I animate the object in blender it matches the footage perfectly but when I render it as a sequence and put it back into AE it doesn't match at all.

What's weird is when I export them out as stills they do match the footage in AE.

Don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure the original footage is 30 fps? Are you sure the comp in AE is 30 fps? Are you sure the imported image sequence in AE is set to be interpreted as 30 fps?

Comment: Yes it's set to 24fps on the sequencer, in after effects and the comp.

Comment: When you import the sequence in after effects, is the duration of the image sequence the same as the duration of the footage?